# My Brother DCP 7065DN Printer is "not available"

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing

I recently installed Ubuntu on my new computer, and now I want to be able to print with it.

So I looked up how to do it, and the tutorial told me to enter some commands and download the `LPR` and `Cupswrapper` driver for my `Brother DCP 7065DN` Printer.

I completed all of the steps, and when I opened my printer menu in the settings, my printer was listed.

But after, when I tested the printer, I didn't work. I checked the properties and the status was Idle - `Waiting for printer to become available`.

Windows works just fine with the printer. Also, I am trying to print wirelessly through the wifi.

I don't think it would be a problem with the driver, since I downloaded it straight from the website.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You must check the configuration file `/etc/printcap`:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo nano /etc/printcap
```

In the open file for Network Connection, replace `:lp` line to the following 2 lines

```
:rm=(ip address of your printer)\
:rp=lp\
```

Example:

```
DCP7065DN:\
        :mx=0:\
        :sd=/var/spool/lpd/dcp7065dn:\
        :sh:\
        :rm=192.168.3.3\
        :rp=lp\
        :if=/usr/local/Brother/Printer/dcp7065dn/lpd/filterdcp7065dn:
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

And Configure your printer on the cups web interface:

Open a web browser and go to `http://localhost:631/printers`.

Click `Modify Printer` and set following parameters:

```
LPD/LPR Host or Printer or AppSocket/HP JetDirect   -(For Device)
lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1         -(For Device URI)
Brother   -(For Make/Manufacturer Selection)
Your printer's name  -(For Model/Driver Selection)
```

Example:

[image]

## [Source](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html)

Comment: When I enter the command, this shows up: '# This file was automatically generated by cupsd(8) from the
# /etc/cups/printers.conf file.  All changes to this file
# will be lost.' I don't see the anything like what you said in there.